# How to calculate the sum of all cells in a raster layer upstream of a specific point?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1

I have a rainfall map which covers large area. However, I'm interested in the total value of rainfall over a specific subcatchment. If I don't have the shapefile which defines the boundary of this subcatchment, is it possible to calculate the sum of the rainfall values upstream of a specific point in ArcGIS? or Do I have to delineate the catchment upstream of this point first?

Comment: This is precisely what the [FlowAccumulation](http://help.arcgis.com/en%20/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Flow_Accumulation/009z00000051000000/) function does.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create the catchment area. If you have the elevation raster for the same region as your rain fall data then you can do this. You need to read the hydrology section of the help file which is found under the spatial analyst section.

Comment: @Hornybydd     Many thanks for your answer. I know how to create the catchment area. However, I was trying to find any other method that enable me to get the value without delineating the catchment upstream of this point